# Laravel 5 eloquent hasManyThrough / belongsToManyThrough relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

In a Laravel 5.2 application I have three models: `User`, `Role` and `Task`. 
A `User` is associated with multiple `Roles`, and a `Role` is associated with multiple `Tasks`. 
Therefore each user is associated to multiple tasks, through their roles.

I am trying to access all `Tasks` associated with a `User`, through their Roles.

The relevant parts of my models look like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{    
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Task', 'App\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}

class Task extends Model
{    
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    } 
}
```

The following returns an SQL error;

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id'
```

It seems to be trying to access the relationship through a (non-existent) foreign key in the Role model, rather than through the pivot table.

```
$user = Auth::user;
$tasks = $user->tasks;
```

How can I access all tasks related to a user through these relationships?

Comment: what foreign key column do you have in role table for saving user id?

Comment: Do you have column `user_id` in roles table?

Answer (score 4):

I have developed a [custom `BelongsToManyThrough` relationship](https://gist.github.com/alexweissman/cae6303d2476d18b4a10eeef38919fcf) which might interest you.  You would need to add the new relation class (as given in my gist; it is too long to paste here), and also override your base `Model` class as described in the gist to implement `belongsToManyThrough`.

Then (assuming you are using Laravel's default table naming schemes - if not, you can specify the joining tables as well), you would define your relationship as:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToManyThrough(
        'App\Task',
        'App\Role');
}
```

`belongsToManyThrough` will not only give you a list of Tasks for your User(s), it will also tell you the Role(s) via which each User has each Task.  For example, if you had:

`$user->tasks()->get()`

The output would look something like:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ban spammers",
        "roles_via": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "slug": "site-admin",
                "name": "Site Administrator",
                "description": "This role is meant for \"site administrators\", who can basically do anything except create, edit, or delete other administrators."
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "slug": "group-admin",
                "name": "Group Administrator",
                "description": "This role is meant for \"group administrators\", who can basically do anything with users in their same group, except other administrators of that group."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Approve posts",
        "roles_via": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "slug": "group-admin",
                "name": "Group Administrator",
                "description": "This role is meant for \"group administrators\", who can basically do anything with users in their same group, except other administrators of that group."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Reboot server",
        "roles_via": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "slug": "site-admin",
                "name": "Site Administrator",
                "description": "This role is meant for \"site administrators\", who can basically do anything except create, edit, or delete other administrators."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My custom relationship does this efficiently, with only a few queries, as opposed to other solutions involving `foreach`, which would create an [n+1 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-select-n1) problem.

Comment: hello alexw where to put this custom relationship query?
i am not clear

Comment: @user2851129 there is actually an updated version of this integrated into our UserFrosting framework: https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/tree/master/app/sprinkles/core/src/Database/Relations.  See the `Unique` trait, `BelongsToManyThrough` relationship class, and our custom [`HasRelationships`](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/app/sprinkles/core/src/Database/Models/Concerns/HasRelationships.php) Model trait.  If you take a look at the Laravel API docs, you can get a feel for how to integrate these.  You can also join us in [chat](https://chat.userfrosting.com)

Answer (score 0):

From the source code you shared it seems that you have `Many to Many` relationships between: `User` and `Role` and between `Role` and `Task`.

The `hasManyThrough` method expects two `One to Many` relationships.

A possible way of getting all `User` related `Task`s would be: (inside the `User` class)

```
public function getTasksAttribute()
{
    $tasks = [];
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        $tasks = array_merge($tasks, $role->tasks);
    }
    return $tasks;
 }
```

You would then be able to access the tasks with:

```
$user->tasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `array_merge()`

One way to do this would be to add a `getTasksAttribute()` method, and using collections.

```
public function getTasksAttribute()
{
    $tasks = new Collection([]);
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        $tasks = $tasks->mergeRecursive($role->tasks);
    }
    return $tasks;
}
```

This can be accessed with `$user->tasks`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 models

User, Role, Permission

User **belongsToMany** Role

Role **belongsToMany** User

Permission **belongsToMany** Role

Role **belongsToMany** Permission

to check if a user has specific permission I made this function in User **model**

```
 public function hasPermission($permission)
    {
        return Permission::where('name', $permission)->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                $query->where('users.id', $this->id);
            });
        })->exists();
    }
```