# Laravel relations in multiple model with belongsToMany and hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on an eCommerce application.

I have 3 models. `Product`, `Color`, `ProductImage`.

The relation between `Product` and `Color` is: **belongsToMany**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entities\Product;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * A product has many colors.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class);
    }
}
```

The relation between `Color` and `ProductImage` is: **hasMany**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entities\Product;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Color extends Model
{
    /**
     * A color has many images.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }
}
```

> Question is how to make a relation between the `Product` and `ProductImage` model?
>
> How to design the `product_images` table?

`id`, `color_id`, `image`

like this?

> my use case is, I will make a slider on a single product page. There will be a Color select option. If a user selects a color, need to load product images associate with that selected color.
>
> Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 eloquent hasManyThrough / belongsToManyThrough relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306242/laravel-5-eloquent-hasmanythrough-belongstomanythrough-relationships)

Comment: @DelenaMalan Thanks for your reply. I will definitely check that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am also working on an e-commerce project and I have designed my database like below.**

A product has multiple product colors but a product color belongs to only one product. product id and color together a compound key(unique) of the product_colors table.

If you have a product T-shirt which id is 101 which product color is red then together 101 and red are a unique product_color.

Product_image belongs to the product and product_colors table. Together product_id and product_color_id are composite key. In case if you have multiple images for the same product id and color then you can save the image as JSON data. which I did for my application.

[image]

Although I have designed my database like fig 01. But if we want to separate the colors table then we could design the database like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need only productImages, you can use `belongsToManyThrough`. But if you need colors and productImages you can do it through the dot.

```
$product->load('colors.images');
```

**UPD**
Read your description, in my point of view, table `images` should have two keys `product_id` and `color_id`. And then do something like this:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}

public function current_image(int $color_id)
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductImage::class)->where('color_id', $color_id);
}
```

Comment: Updated question, how to design `product_images` table?

Comment: As `Product` has many `Colors` and `Color` has many `Products`, so multiple `color_id` will be there in the `product_images` table. Then how to get a single `product` related images without `product_id` or something?